# Write http stream in a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http, request

I'm having problems trying to write a chunk buffer into a file. My problem is basically that the file only contains the last bytes of the output buffer. The chunk buffer is very large, and my file.out is truncated, the last items are correct.

Here is my code

```
    var reqChart = http.request(chart, function(res1) {

    res1.setEncoding( 'utf8' );

    res1.on('data', function (chunk) {

        var fs = require('fs');


        //var b = new Buffer(chunk.length);
        var c = "";

        for (var i = 0;i < chunk.length;i++) {
         //   b[i] = chunk[i];
            c = c  + chunk[i]
        }

        console.log(c);

        fs.writeFile("rich.txt", c,  "utf-8",function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

And if you are interested here is the BEGINNING the input I get in my file vs the BEGINNING of the "console.log" of my variable... I already tried to write the "console.log" to a file but same results.

File

```
0,0.120179572670496],[1498028100000,0.105581318680705],[1498028400000,0.167319933562371],[1498028700000,0.147574197583768],[1498029000000,0.114172853959319],[1498029300000,0.241186960587686],[1498029600000,1.45701290672775],[1498029900000,0.154756395075166],[1498030200000,0.0836631006369253],[1498030500000,0.0800486694467188],[1498030800000,0.0861569133026863],[1498031100000,0.092360872083502],[1498031400000,0.0790707908354345],[1498031700000,0.129877438815933],[1498032000000,0.118812121796025],[1498032300000,0.0989746376933164],[1498032600000,2.30001837257628],[1498032900000,0.313639093279438],[1498033200000,0.227936449562983],
```

Buffer/Variable/log

```
{"requestData":{"options":{"width":950,"gui_component_mode":1,"exporttocsv":1,"only_stacks_in_legend":false,"reverse_axis":false,"height":446,"datasetTitle":"","legend_average":false,"legend_maximum":false,"legend_minimum":false},"model_group":101,"name":"autil_17","model":"nmis_graph","dataset_id":0,"owner_cid":"c3","data_source_type":"chart","model_view":"graph","parameters":{"graph_type":"interface","resource_index":"17","nmis_data_type":null,"value_column":"value","node":"RT01459","axis":0,"end_date_raw":1498095300,"substitutions":{"time.start":1497922702,"time.end":1498095502},"time_column":"time","translation":"","field":"","lineType":"line","period":"2d","index_graph_type":"autil","resource":"interface","start_date_raw":1497922500,"resolution":300,"class":null},"data_source":"local_nmis","translation":null},"replyData":{"options":{"subtitleText":"ENTERPRISE_RT01","titleText":"Interface gigabitethernet0-2-3913","legend_raw":"    Avg In     Max In Avg 12.76 % Max 98.99 % \\n     Avg Out     Max Out Avg 4.98 % Max 52.49 % \\n","yAxis0TitleText":"% Avg Util"},"stacking":"normal","meta_data":{"time_start":1497922500,"start_date_input":"2017-06-19 20:35:00","end_date_input":"2017-06-21 20:35:00"},"data":[{"yAxis":0,"reverse_axis":0,"valueDecimals":2,"value_min":-98.9864025844157,"color":"#00BFFF","suffix":"","dataset_multiplier":1,"sum":-7373.17229868631,"connectNulls":0,"stack":1,"value_max":-0.0591203443255937,"name":"Avg In","data":[[1497922500000,-0.7137202476565],[1497922800000,-1.43305756579003],[1497923100000,-0.150464409649807],[1497923400000,-0.150475661479925],[1497923700000,-0.100369773564214],[1497924000000,-0.0893947123021048]
```

I thought maybe in a timeout function or something, but the log is WRITING THE INFO THE TERMINAL, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize that you reset c at every chunk as its locally scoped?:

```
var c="";//not resetted
res1.on('data', function (chunk) {
    c+=chunk;
}
```

And you need to await the stream to finish:

```
res1.on("end",function(){
 console.log(c);
var fs = require('fs');
 fs.writeFile("rich.txt", c,  "utf-8",function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. 
I just pasted your piece of code and it worked, the file is complete. 


:)

Comment: @ricardo youre welcome ;). Please also have a look at Bretts answer. Piping can be really useful when dealing with streams...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're writing the file while you are at `stream.on('data',...`. You need to add all that data to a file, and use `stream.on('end',...` event to write to a file. I hope this example helps

```
var fs = require('fs');
// Some example of getting original data
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
var data = '';

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data+=chunk;
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(data);
    fs.writeFile("rich.txt", data,  "utf-8",function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Now copying your code and modifying it:

```
var reqChart = http.request(chart, (res1) => {
    res1.setEncoding('utf8');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var c = "";

    res1.on('data', function (chunk) {
        //var b = new Buffer(chunk.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
            //   b[i] = chunk[i];
            c = c + chunk[i]
        }
        console.log(c);
    });

    res1.on('end', function () {
        fs.writeFile("rich.txt", c, "utf-8", function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: It looks like he's trying to save the response from an HTTP request to a file, not read a file.

Comment: Awesome Lemme try.

Answer (score 1):

The `pipe` function for streams would make your life a lot easier.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

const output = fs.createWriteStream('output.html'); // change to rich.txt
const url = 'http://example.com'; // change to chart URL

http.get(url, response => {
    response.pipe(output);
});
```